# Docx4j, there is no prefix registered for Bibliography

Tags: jaxb, docx4j

I'm trying to add bibliography & citation to docx file using Docx4j. However the XML generated by library has automatically created namespace:

```
<ns30:Source>
```

MS Word unfortunetely doesnt show such kind of source as a source. After some trials & erros I discovered that enough is to change the namespace:

```
<b:Source>
```

Probably the problem is that in Docx4J this namespace is not defined in NamespacePrefixMappings class.

How Can I add or define my own namespace prefix mappings? Or can I somehow force Docx4j for using particular prefix for part? Anything where the result will be XML with namespace "b" will be good advice for me. I would like to avoid downloading Docx4j source, modyfing source and having customized version of library.

Comment: What version of Word are you reporting this against?

Comment: Word 2010 & Word 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT-20151020.jar contains https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/089bce035e847dc473b95080a7106f35470fa48e which adds the mapping to NamespacePrefixMappings

Comment: Hi. I have the latest version of docx4j. But this problem exist yet. When I add some sources it adds them with 'ns30' and not 'b'. How can I solve the problem?

I have docx4j-3.2.2.jar

Comment: v3.3.0 is currently the latest version (not 3.2.2)

Comment: Could you please answer this question also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076030/how-can-i-detect-org-docx4j-wml-instrtext-when-parsing-docx-with-docx4j