# How can I detect org.docx4j.wml.instrText when parsing DOCX with docx4j?

Tags: docx4j

I want to pars a docx file with docx4j library.

I need to detect org.docx4j.wml.instrText objects but actually it returns org.docx4j.wml.Text instead of org.docx4j.wml.instrText.

I found a solution that was working with older version of this library here:

http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/can-i-just-don-t-load-contents-of-w-instrtext-into-text-t193.html

Actually this solution:

```
 ((javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement)((org.docx4j.wml.Text) o).getParent()).getName().getLocalPart()
```

But with the latest update it does not work. Could you please tell me what changes I have to make on this code?

Actually it make a type casting error that can not convert org.docx4j.wml.R to JAXBElement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent of the Text object, given by:

```
 ((org.docx4j.wml.Text) o).getParent()
```

is, as the error says, a org.docx4j.wml.R, which you can't cast to JAXBElement.

To identify your object in this case, try:

```
((javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement)o).getName().getLocalPart()
```

Comment: but it doesn't work in latest night release. Please test it there.

Comment: You'll need to provide a complete test case (working Java code + input docx)

Comment: ClassFinder texts = new ClassFinder(Text.class);
new TraversalUtil(p, texts);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for (Object text : texts.results) { 
    

   
   
   String qname =((javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement)tex).getName().getLocalPart();

if(tex.getParent() instanceof FldChar){
 
}
else{
sb.append(tex.getValue());
}

Comment: Hi jason i'm not able to cast tex as a jaxbelement. I just want to avoid field char and insertext while appending the Text.

Comment: Why not cast it to Text?!

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.docx4j.wml.Text cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement

Comment: I forgot to insert 1 line in the first comment Text tex = (Text)text;